# How to fix UIStackView constraint issue

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have the following layout in a UIStackViewView. It is a image and two labels. The design view is what I'd like the runtime view to appear as. But when it runs, everything gets push to the right.

[image]

Constraint warnings, which I can't fix:

[image]

Run-time view:

[image]

Any suggestions how I can fix this? The UIStackView is supposed to make complex layouts simpler to manage but I can't even get it to work with just three elements.

Comment: try to use an actual image in your UIImageView

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the stack view?

Comment: You could also try to make `horisontal compression resistanse priority` of your imageView less

Comment: I do have an actual image in the view now. But Xcode doesn't allow me to change the size so no difference in appearance.  horisontal compression resistanse priority has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not giving constraints to imageView so its taking all the space to the right.

If you add the aspect-size constraint or give a width constraint then it will constraint the image to the left and get the desired results.

Comment: Yes - I gave the imageview width and height constraints. Now it looks fine 6 & 6 Plus. But the "Middle Text" does not show 4 and 5. Do you have some idea what might be wrong?